# Is there a way to refactor multiple inline CSS in a ternary operator using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

Here is a snippet of the code located in a JSX file:

```
  <li onClick={handleClick} style={{ 
      textDecoration: isDone ? "line-through"  : "none", 
      background: isDone ? "#afc97e" : null, 
      color: isDone ? "#fff" : null }}
      >
  </li>
```

Comment: You could refactor it into a separate style object, then just do `style={isDone && styleObject}`, or use CSS and apply a className.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a constant with the isDone styles and use the help of the spread operator, I don't know how your component is written, but this is a very generalist example. Hope it helps.

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { isDone } = props;
  const isDoneStyles = {
    textDecoration: 'line-through',
    background: #afc97e,
    color: #fff
  };
  return(
    <li onClick={handleClick} style={{isDone ? ...isDoneStyles : ...{ textDecoration: none } }}>
    </li> 
  )
};
```

Comment: Were you able to implement this on your code? Important parts here are declaring a constant object and destructuring it with the ternary operator.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this? Glad to help

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply) Yes! It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I worked with what you suggested. I placed all of the CSS attributes into a const object, and I wrote a ternary operator like so: style={isDone ? {...customStyle} : null}